# MVC 2 - Are Sattelite assemblies required for embedded resources? Embedded  resources not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, localization, wix, wix3.5, satellite-assembly

Hello I have been working on an MVC 2.0 web application.
This has the requirement to switch between 2 languages.

The existing solution did not work well as the MVC [DisplayName] attributes and data annotation error messages etc did not work as they were not culture aware in MVC 2.0.

I followed the example here:
http://adamyan.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html#!/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

With a few tweaks it is all working perfectly in my Visual studio Environment and switches language and uses the MVC diplay name etc fine now.
I am using embedded resources and have an English resx file (e.g MyPage.resx) and the culture version (e.g. MyPage.cy-GB.resx).

The problem is when I install this into a production environment it is not switching languages.
I am baffled since I thought these embedded resources would be part of the main web application dll so it should have no trouble finding the matching resource?

I know it is definitely changing the culture on the current thread. It just isn't loading the matching resource.

The application is installed using WIX without harvesting but I have included all files (aspx etc). Previously it was using a satellite assembly and creating a resource dll in the bin folder with the culture name. I removed this as I am just using embedded resources as mentioned. Is the satellite assembly a requirement for this? I am quite happy for them to be embedded.

I am really confused about how to resolve this so any advice would be very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MyPage.cy-GB.resx is embedded in the satellite assembly. It is necessary, in fact embedded resources are all that goes into satellite assemblies.

Comment: There is no satellite assemby at the moment as no mypage dll is created. Are you saying I must create a satellite dll for it to work? (PS: I haven't done that before but have seen some examples how to do it using assembly linker - I would prefer to avoid it unless it is necessary)
thanks.

Comment: There should be a satellite assembly. When you compile your website, in the bin folder there ought to be an assembly named <whatever your website project is>.dll, and then a folder cy-GB\ with the satellite assembly in it.

Comment: I included the original resource files back into the project and I get a resource.dll in the folder. This does not work for my resx files which are in folders such as /Resources/Views/Index.resx and  Index.cy-GB.resx. (these are public embedded with a custom namespace.

Building in Visual Studio does not create DLLS anywhere for these.
The Resources folder is copied to the bin folder which contains the child folder with resx and designer.cs files.

The resource.dll files are as you say in bin/cy-GB. Visual studio created another bin folder too with a cy-GB folder but is empty. Very confusing.

Comment: I created a new  project and added two resource files and it all works as you say. I then added two new new resx files to the existing project and it doesn't work as they are not created in the expected folder as a dll. This is obviosuly the issue..